# Android - How to pause music when home button pressed

Tags: android, media-player

In my application I have a *listview* of some sounds.
By touch any of them a custom alertDialog pop-up and user can play and seek the sound.

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment
{
    ...
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                playAudio audio = new playAudio(context, songPath);
                audio.show();
            }
    });
}
```

for play sound I used MediaPlayer in playAudio class(playAudio.java).

```
public class playAudio extends Dialog 
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play_audio)
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {                  
                mp.setDataSource(songPath);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the problem : when a sound is playing in my alertDialog and user press home button, sound doesn't pause.I know I can start and pause sound with *onPause()* and *onResume()* methods in MainActivity but I don't know how am I suppose to pass mp(my mediaplayer object) to MainActivity.
or is there any other solution for pause music when home button is pressed?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mp.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mp.start();
    super.onResume();
}
```

**EDIT:** I don't know is it good to do such thing or not, but I defined mp public static and use it in my MainActivity in onResume and onPause.it worked.

Comment: You should use a service class to play music instead of hardcoding into Dialog's or Activity's class

Comment: @kaustubhpatange Thanks for your advice. I don't know is it good to do such thing but I defined mp public static and use it in my MainActivity and it worked.